# Unable to code the right ratios for a drawing in Java

Tags: java, graphics2d

So I have been trying to make this: [image]

but my problem is that I do not know how to create such ratios in Java. Specifically, I want to be able to implement this:

> "...an upright ...cross, whose [four] arms of equal length are a sixth longer than their width" and so the distance from the perpendicular arm to the shortest edge is always the width of an arm.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RedCross extends JPanel
{
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);  // Call JPanel's paintComponent method
                              //   to paint the background
    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    int xoo = (getWidth() * 3) / 16;
    int yoo = (getHeight() * 3) / 16;
    if (getHeight() < getWidth())
    {
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillRect(xCenter - (yoo / 2), yoo, yoo, getHeight() - 2 * yoo);
      g.fillRect(xCenter - (5 * yoo) / 3, 13 * yoo / 6, getHeight() - 2 * yoo, yoo);
    }
    
    else
    {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(13 * xoo / 6, yCenter - (5 * xoo) / 3, xoo, getWidth() - 2 * xoo);
    g.fillRect(xoo, yCenter - (xoo / 2), getWidth() - 2 * xoo, xoo);
  }
  }
    
  

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Red Cross");
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 200, 200);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    RedCross panel = new RedCross();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Container c = window.getContentPane();
    c.add(panel);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

My code draws a cross as desired, but the ratios are disproportional and I'm not familiar enough with Java to know how to change the aspect ratio of the output image.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Please read [mcve] and add a clear description of how your code behaves. Beyond that - you solve such problems by first using a pen and a piece of paper to figure manually what exactly needs to happen. Then you look at your code to figure where your algorithm goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been too vague originally. I was able to draw the cross, but I have no idea how to scale it at all.

Comment: @JustAMathematician what do you mean by,  you don't know to create ratios in Java ? tell us your exact problem ?

Comment: My problem is as follows: I have created a cross, but now I would like to resize it such that it matches the given ratios. Specifically, the quoted bit. My code just draws a cross - it does not follow the specifications.